# Renaming class doesn't affect datatype

Tags: ontology, protege

I'm working with an ontology and I renamed some of the classes, using the `Refactor -> Rename entity` option on Protégé.

I'm using this ontology as an import for another one, in which some individuals where declared to be of the type of that class.

I was expecting this to be renamed as well, but when I open my second ontology I see it has the new class and the old class. And all individuals reference to the old class.

How can I get this fixed so that renaming actually affects all the relationships?

As a workaround I just copied and pasted the instances under the correct classes, but I guess there is a way to avoid this.

Comment: If the second ontology is not opened when you do the rename, Protege has no way of knowing what else needs renaming - changes are applied only to the main ontology opened, not to its imports closure. You'll have to do the renaming twice, in both ontologies.

Comment: @Ignazio thanks, and if I rename it on the second ontology does it affect the imported one? In any case, you should set the comment as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one